# iOS Swift: Parsing response json with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, json, swift, afnetworking-2

So, I am using AFNetworking 2.0 (ObjC framework with Bridging-Header) to make some requests on a local server. I have followed a few tutorials to code it using Swift. This is the code:

```
var success = { (operation:AFHTTPRequestOperation!, response:AnyObject!) -> Void in
    println(response.description)
    successBlock(result:response.description)
}

var failure = { (operation:AFHTTPRequestOperation!, response:NSError!) -> Void in
    println(response.description)
    errorBlock(error:response.description)
}

var manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer();
manager.GET("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/manufacturer", parameters: nil, success: success, failure: failure)
```

It retrieves the json and prints it successfully. The response is something like this:

```
(
        {
        "_id" = 539f0973e3c7f4ab1f6078f5;
        name = Manufacturer01;
    },
        {
        "_id" = 539f18c5e3c7f4ab1f6078f6;
        name = Manufacturer02;
    }
)
```

However, I am unable to parse it... I tried `response[0]` to get the first element, but it crashes the simulator and even Xcode6 when I try to do: `(lldb) > po response[0]`. I tried everything, every example I have seen explains how to print the result but nothing about parsing each field.

The `response` object looks like this when I try to debug it:

```
value = Some {
    Some = (instance_type = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x0b240710 -> 0x00bc5da0 (void *)0x00bc5db4: __NSCFArray)
  }
```

Any clue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also have this issue. How on Earth do i assign the JSON Dictionary values to a string variable? I have a var `var serverID:String?` and when trying `self.serverID = responseObject["server_id"] as? String` it crashes Xcode

Comment: I had success with this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259756/unable-to-parse-json-from-afnetworkings-responseobject

Comment: @heycarsten Unfortunately I get EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on Simulator and EXC_BREAKPOINT on Device with that code. :(

Comment: @Sean It seems automatically convert to NUMBER TYPE, not String!!! I had same issue, and I try to find a way to convert as String.

Comment: hi any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if let responseArray = response as? NSArray {
    let firstElement = responseArray[0]
    // do something with the first element
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lays within sending it back in the successBlock. Since the retrieved information ain't presented properly in the description object.

```
var jsonArrayDictionary = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]]

for item in jsonArrayDictionary {
     dump(item["_id"] as? String)
     dump(item["name"] as? String)
}
```

That should probably do it.

Answer (score -5):

Your example response is not valid JSON.

If your example is an Array, JSON would have square brackets instead of parens, field names in quotes and colons instead of equals signs. For example:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1234,
    "name": "foo bar"
  },
  {
    "_id": 12122,
    "name": "baz"
  }
]
```

Also see one of the JSON linters, e.g.: [jsonlint.com](http://www.jsonlint.com)

Comment: It's probably the contents of the dictionary printed in the debugger.

Comment: @mAu is right. The json is well constructed, that is the debugger representation.